# Merge Request: [xbox-controller] -> [controllers]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

An xbox controller is a controller (obviously), but also:

- Most questions under [xbox-controller](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-controller) have the [controllers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/controllers) tag as well.
- Any questions specific to the xbox controller already specifies this in the Title/Question body.

The current [synonyms](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/controllers/synonyms) for the [controllers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/controllers) tag are:

- [xbox-360-controller](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-360-controller)
- [controller](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/controller)
- [gamepad](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gamepad)

Comment: If we do this, we need to merge all possible [tag:controllers]-like tags into [tag:controllers].

Comment: [tag:controllers] is already a pretty bad tag that should be removed form most questions.

Comment: Maybe we should put it under a general [tag:peripherals] tag.

Comment: @Yawus - There's already been a discussion to that effect here: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1596/differences-between-controllers-and-peripherals

Comment: @OrigamiRobot - I don't see why it's such a bad tag, it's a specific type of hardware that a lot of people have issues with. I have no problem with a question tagged "*xbox, controllers*" as that instantly tells me what the question is about. Either way that is a discussion for another question, the point of this post is to stop the questions being tagged "*xbox, controllers, xbox-controller*"

Comment: Also @Yawus - as per your first statement, here is the list of [synonyms](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/controllers/synonyms) for controllers already. Just noticed myself that xbox-360-controller is already in that list as well! Even more reason to add xbox-controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been actioned as part of the [Arqade Cleanup effort of 2013](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7820/cleanup-2013-its-time-for-burnination).