# Cleanup 2014: It's time for burnination!

Tags: discussion, tags

A continuation of [The Great Arqade Cleanup of 2012](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4758/52800). Call this the <strike>2013</strike> 2014 edition if you wish.

We've still got some horrible tags. I require upvotes as authorisation of removing them.

This post is primarily focussed on tags to delete - rather than tags to fix. A lot of our tags are still in pretty good condition after the community effort last year and don't need fixing although there are some instances and these should be bought up in their own questions.

Specifically, the types of tag that should be mentioned in this question are as follows;

- Meta Tags: tags describing the question
- Type 3: tags that mean different things from game to game
- Type 6: tags which mean roughly the same thing in different games, but are otherwise very unlikely to be used as filters by themselves

For more elaborate explanations for what is meant by "meta tags", "type 3", etc, see the [original cleanup post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4758/52800) and [the discussion that spawned it](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4636/52800).

As is the correct process for a post like this, post each tag or group of related tags in individual answers to this question so that they can be voted on accordingly, once enough votes have been reached for a particular tag or group of related tags, they will be burned.

**As your suggestion is burninated it would be good if you'd remove the answer associated with the tag that was burned to keep this post nice and clean and obvious what work is outstanding for the people who're voting. Update the list below to indicate which tags have been burned.**

Burned, Merged or Cleaned so far:
[save-games](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/save-games) [windowed-mode](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windowed-mode) [fullscreen](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fullscreen) [osx-lion](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx-lion) [repair](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/repair) [lan](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lan) [multiplayer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiplayer) [xbox-controller](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-controller) [mmo](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mmo) [simulation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simulation) [hosting](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hosting) [cross-platform](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-platform) [browser-based](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/browser-based) [demo](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/demo) [system-requirements](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-requirements) [dvd](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dvd) [xbox-gamertag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-gamertag) [nintendo](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nintendo) [xbox](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox) [macro](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macro) [dlc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dlc) [freemium](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/freemium)

Comment: While going through the tags I saw that there's a fair few that need tag wikis, and others that have bad tag wiki excerpts. Can we incorporate a clean up of bad tag wikis into this maelstrom of hellfire somewhere?

Comment: No - tag wikis will be covered in an upcoming episode of kalina vs meta. This is all about burning tags we don't need.

Comment: @fredley http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1594/top-tags-requiring-a-tag-wiki

Comment: Are we or are we not using [[tag:hosting]] anymore? I can't tell from the deleted post here what conditions under which it is tolerated on a question, and its tag wiki hasn't been updated with any usage instructions.

Comment: Cleaned but kept for questions specifically about hosting, rather than as a meta tag for questions about a game and hosting

Answer (score 5):

[hard-drive](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-drive) and [audio-hardware](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio-hardware) can just be made synonyms of [hardware](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware) in cases where simply removing them isn't possible.

And: [power-supply](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-supply)

Comment: [tag:hard-drive] is considered useful as per [this meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4981/clean-up-graphics-card-monitor-others-hardware)

Comment: @3ventic maybe it's time to change.

Answer (score 3):

[cheats](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cheats) should be removed from most questions.

Valid questions for the tag include

- [How do GameShark codes work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/76858/how-do-gameshark-codes-work)
- [Using game trainers on a laptop without numlock or numpad](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33000/using-game-trainers-on-a-laptop-without-numlock-or-numpad)
- [What prevents users from cheating from outside a game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7205/what-prevents-users-from-cheating-from-outside-a-game)

Comment: This is a big tag to burn, this is going to need more upvotes and/or further discussion before we action it

Comment: What about my question on [how gameshark codes work](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/76858/how-do-gameshark-codes-work)? What will that be tagged as?

Comment: @Ktash - perhaps 'Gameshark'

Comment: @Robotnik In truth it is about all similar devices. There are many memory modifying cheat devices like Gameshark, and I mention both that and the Game Genie in my post. There is also action replay and [a few others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheat_cartridge). The question title may only say Gameshark, but as I say in the question, they all use the same technique, so the question applies to all. Not sure gameshark is the appropriate tag. I think it is cheating.

Comment: @Ktash If there happen to be one or two questions that don't have better tags, that's fine.  The overall point is the tag shouldn't be used when asking for cheats in a game.

Comment: IIRC there used to be a question about the Konami code that suited the [cheats] tag, but I think it's been deleted (at least, I can't find it).

Answer (score 1):

[version-differences](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-differences)

- It's an ambiguous tag (Type 3)
- Questions about version differences should simply be tagged with the game(s)/console(s) in question.

Only the questions below have [version-differences](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-differences) as their only tag, and both are closed:

- https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/31147/how-do-i-choose-between-the-console-and-pc-versions-of-a-game (Too Broad)
- https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/16639/does-a-website-exist-that-compares-the-versions-of-the-same-game-on-different-pl (Off Topic: Shopping Rec)

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28395/ and http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/16639/

Comment: @MBraedley - nice, somehow I missed those. Added the game tag to the former. The latter is a shopping rec, so I've VTCd that one

Answer (score -9):

[achievements](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/achievements)

It's not because achievements are part of your core experience that you are any wiser for answering this for all achievements across all games.

That's like saying: 
"There are item drops in Skyrim, I know *everything* about that game. So I am perfectly knowledgeable about any items in all games."

Comment: Here we go again...

Comment: [There's a meta about this particular tag](//meta.arqade.com/a/720/3062). There might actually be more than one, because that's not the one I remembered reading about it when I went hunting, either. One of the basic arguments is that it's useful for people who go achievement hunting in games so they can easily sort the questions.

Comment: @Sterno what does this tag to that simply searching for "achievement" doesn't do?

Comment: I'm not someone who uses it, so I don't know. I just wanted to mention I'd seen it discussed. Ask @FAE... I'm pretty sure she was a proponent of it.

Comment: I'm still in favor of keeping the achievement tag.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot At a quick glance, apparently its annoying because you get different results searching for "achievement" versus "achievements", and the tag removes that issue. [Related chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4783817#4783817)

Comment: @Sterno This difference is simply caused by most of these posts containing the word achievement, and not the plural.

Comment: @arperum Right. Which makes them harder to find than if they just had a tag.  There are probably some that never even say the word "achievement".

Comment: @Sterno You are right there, some of them contain words such as "award" for the questions tagged, but not containing the word: [click here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=[achievements]+-achievement+is%3Aquestion)

Comment: I am still in favour of keeping the achievement tag. It's up to community consensus though - if we end up pretty evenly matched it will probably be worth breaking this out into its own, new, discussion.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot People who don't like achievements can ignore the tag, instantly sort-filtering their questions.

Comment: @RavenDreamer It's not about not liking achievements.  I love achievements.  I just think it's too broad a tag and serves no purpose that searching via non-tags doesn't solve.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot The problem is that there is no consistency without the tag. Games call "achievements" any number of things, and Stack Exchange's engine is a lot better with tag-search than text-search.

Comment: Yes, but who is going looking for achievements for games they don't own? search "[tag:game-name] whatever-they-call-achievements"

Comment: @OrigamiRobot So what about cross platform games? How does the guy looking for PS3 Trophies find the answer referencing 360's live-achievements through search?

Comment: There is a pretty dedicated segment of gamers who are really, really into game completion and achievement hunting/farming/(and gathering?). I don't care two whits about the tag personally, but I definitely see the utility to that segment of the gaming population even on games they don't (yet) own.

Comment: Not to mention, I'm fairly sure [achievement] helps our SEO

Comment: There was also a [more recent meta last year during the cleanup](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/4956/15643). The community was split down the middle on it, and it is a big clean up task. Power users have found it useful, so it was decided that we would keep it, at least for now. If it becomes a problem, then we can address it on its own.