# Is there a way to search for questions that are tagged only with the specified tag?

Tags: support, search

Whilst researching for the [Version Differences Tag Cleanup Post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8325/28182), I attempted to find questions that were only tagged with [version-differences](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-differences), and no other tag. As MBraedley points out, I missed a couple.

What would have been neat, is the ability to search for questions that are **only** tagged with the tag(s) specified. Is this possible?

For example, searches we can currently perform:

- **[[version-differences]](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-differences)** (77 results)

  - Takes me to the tag's '[newest](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-differences)' page (as opposed to the Search Results page).
  - Questions can still have multiple tags
  - Questions are ordered newest->oldest
- **[[version-differences] is:question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bversion-differences%5D%20is:question)** (77 results)

  - Takes me to the search results page
  - Questions can still have multiple tags
  - Questions are ordered oldest->newest
- **[[version-differences] is:question -[xbox]](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bversion-differences%5D%20is:question)** (76 results)

  - Search Results page
  - Questions still have multiple tags
  - oldest->newest
  - excludes the [xbox](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox) tag

But I cannot list every tag with the '-' operator (despite the massive impracticality on my part, I daresay there's a limit on search text length). So, is there a search I can perform to exclude all tags, except the one I specified?

Comment: See this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148977/230957

Comment: Yeah, I think a data explorer query is the best option.

Comment: @3ventic/MBraedley - IIRC the data explorer can be out of date by almost a month, which is fine for slower moving tags, but the data for the ones that see more activity would go stale fairly quickly. Nevertheless if its the only possible way at this time, Then I guess I'll deal :). Care to add it as an answer?

Comment: @Robotnik it's now [updated weekly](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/stack-exchange-cc-data-now-hosted-by-the-internet-archive/).  So not 100% coverage, but pretty good.

Comment: @MBraedley - good spot! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FY8hQ/) to use the StackExchange API to find questions that only have one tag. Specify the tag at the top of the script in `var tag = 'taghere'`.

Alternatively, use the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/163894/questions-with-a-single-tag?TagName=version-differences).

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to fix that query to be a bit better once I get the chance.

Comment: Doing that query the "proper" way was harder than I originally thought.  Note that results may not be up to date.

Comment: @MBraedley - Heh, I was having a jab at it too. Nice work

Comment: I recommend you add this SEDE query to [Interesting queries on Data Explorer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49943/interesting-queries-on-data-explorer)