# Do we need the [ultimate-team] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, ambiguous-tags

I stumbled across [ultimate-team](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultimate-team) today, and after a brief read of what 'Ultimate Team' actually is:

> FIFA Ultimate Team (commonly called FUT or sometimes UT) is a mode in FIFA where you build teams using any players from all the leagues to play offline and online.
>   <sub>- [FIFA Addiction](http://fifaaddiction.com/ultimate-team/what-is-fifa-ut/)</sub>

I'm wondering whether we need it as a tag?

It appears to be referring to a game mode within the FIFA series, but the tag has also been used for [some](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/29149/28182) [Madden](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/30754/28182) [questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/45582/28182).

I'm no expert in FIFA or Madden, so I ask: Is this game mode large enough to warrant it's own tag, separate to the game tag(s)? If so, should we distinguish between FIFA and Madden's versions by splitting and renaming it [fifa-ultimate-team](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fifa-ultimate-team)/[madden-ultimate-team](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/madden-ultimate-team) to reduce the ambiguity?

If it's not useful, should we just remove it entirely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've also had a quick look and yes, this appears to be a game mode rather than a game and this tag in its current use is ambiguous and inconsistently applied. This tag in my opinion falls under the [meta tags section and possibly even with differing meanings in different games](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7820/cleanup-2014-its-time-for-burnination) of the tag cleanup we did a few years ago and should be removed.

Comment: The question then is: Burnination by a mod or just manually edit (and bump) 16 questions?

Comment: Ive already been told 15 or so is appropriate for a bump

Comment: @MrLemon / Timelord64 - I'm giving it a couple of days to see if anyone else wants to chime in to the contrary, after which we can probably just edit to remove them :)

Comment: [tag:ultimate-team] has now been removed from all questions, The auto-tag cleanup script will remove the tag entirely at some point