# Is there a need for a [suggested-order] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've just discovered the low-usage [suggested-order](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suggested-order) tag. It has few enough questions to seem unnecessary, and its intended purpose seems too vague to be any useful as a tag. Should we keep it or destroy it?

Comment: My gut says no; it feels like a meta tag that should be cleaned up. I could see arguments for classifying it as a [type 6](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4636/sorting-out-the-tagging-mess) potentially useful tag though

Comment: I don't see how this tag would be useful. If you're searching for the order to play games in, you'd search using the series tag, not "suggested order" because the person searching doesn't care about every other series that that tag is being used for, they want results for the series they're inquiring about. The keywords would show up if you searched for those words, but there's no need to add a tag for it. That's all in addition to the fact it's a meta tag.

Comment: The questions marked with this tag combined have about 100 votes, with the most popular being [one about the Portal series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20975/should-i-play-portal-before-portal-2) with 94 votes at the time of this comment's posting.

Comment: @Unionhawk I'm surprised to see the achievements tag still around, if it was slated for removal that long ago

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer - it was suggested for removal but the community [voted to keep it](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7833/28182) as a way to categorise,  search,  favourite (or hide) questions about achievements.

Answer (score 9):

I am going to say no, this tag is not needed.

My reasoning is that the tag is basically the question itself. Let's do an experiment: If all you know about a question is that it is tagged [suggested-order](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suggested-order) and [series-name-here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/series-name-here), try to guess what the body of my question could possibly contain. There's really only one answer: "What order should I play the [Series] games in?" (Or, in rare cases, "What order should I play [subset of Series games] in?") It's a meta tag which does not add anything to enrich the question in any way.

Additionally, you can't really be an "expert" on the order in which to play games. Generally speaking, there's usually just one official order for a given series anyway, and it's easy enough to look up.

Answer (score 4):

I created the [suggested-order](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suggested-order) tag thinking it would be a good way to categorize questions. However, after reading [Mage Xy’s answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12780/181240), I’m seeing why I should have used the existing tags for [game-series-name](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-series-name).

I borrowed the tag idea from [Sci-Fi and Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suggested-order?sort=votes). After seeing several similar questions on Arqade, I incorrectly assumed that the tag would also be a good fit here. In hindsight, I should have created a meta discussion before making the tag.

**Go ahead and burninate the tag. In the future, I’ll use series specific tags like [portal-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/portal-series).**